# React useEffect dependency of useCallback always triggers render

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, usecallback

I have a mystery.  Consider the following custom React hook that fetches data by time period and stores the results in a `Map`:

```
export function useDataByPeriod(dateRanges: PeriodFilter[]) {
    const isMounted = useMountedState();

    const [data, setData] = useState(
        new Map(
            dateRanges.map(dateRange => [
                dateRange,
                makeAsyncIsLoading({ isLoading: false }) as AsyncState<MyData[]>
            ])
        )
    );

    const updateData = useCallback(
        (period: PeriodFilter, asyncState: AsyncState<MyData[]>) => {
            const isSafeToSetData = isMounted === undefined || (isMounted !== undefined && isMounted());
            if (isSafeToSetData) {
                setData(new Map(data.set(period, asyncState)));
            }
        },
        [setData, data, isMounted]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (dateRanges.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        const loadData = () => {
            const client = makeClient();
            dateRanges.map(dateRange => {
                updateData(dateRange, makeAsyncIsLoading({ isLoading: true }));

                return client
                    .getData(dateRange.dateFrom, dateRange.dateTo)
                    .then(periodData => {
                        updateData(dateRange, makeAsyncData(periodData));
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        const errorString = `Problem fetching ${dateRange.displayPeriod} (${dateRange.dateFrom} - ${dateRange.dateTo})`;
                        console.error(errorString, error);
                        updateData(dateRange, makeAsyncError(errorString));
                    });
            });
        };

        loadData();
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [dateRanges /*, updateData - for some reason when included this triggers infinite renders */]);

    return data;
}
```

The `useEffect` is being repeatedly triggered when `updateData` is added as a dependency. If I exclude it as a dependency then everything works / behaves as expected but `eslint` complains I'm violating `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.

Given `updateData` has been `useCallback`-ed I'm at a loss to understand why it should repeatedly trigger renders.  Can anyone shed any light please?

Comment: Did you try removing setData from the dependency array in the useCallback?

Comment: Given setData is a dependency isn't that just creating the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` issue in a different place?

Comment: I think the problem is that the "data" variable is included in the dependency array of useCallback. Every time you setData, the data variable is changed that triggers useCallback to provide new updateData and that triggers useEffect. Try to implement updateData without a dependecy on the data variable. you can do something like setData(d=>new Map(d.set(period, asyncState)) to avoid passing "data" variable to useCallback

Comment: Also are you sure that useMountedState returns same ref ? Besides that I think @jure is right

Comment: @jure you were exactly right! Thanks!  Do you want to post this as an answer and I'll accept it?  No sweat if you can't be bothered but I want to give credit where it's due. I'll write up what I have now  - but please do leave your answer and I'll accept that instead.  Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnReilly glad it worked. I tried to compose an answer.  not so easy to explain the behavior with words :) guess this is a bit confusing part of react hooks.

Comment: You did an excellent job of explaining it!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem lies in the `useCallback/useEffect` used in combination. One has to be careful with dependency arrays in both `useCallback` and `useEffect`, as the change in  the `useCallback` dependency array will trigger the `useEffect` to run.

The `“data”` variable is used inside `useCallback` dependency array, and when the setData is called react will rerun function component with new value for `data` variable and that triggers a chain of calls.

Call stack would look something like this:

1. useEffect run
2. updateData called
3. setState called
4. component re-renders with new state data
5. new value for `data` triggers useCallback
6. `updateData` changed
7. triggers `useEffect` again

To solve the problem you would need to remove the `“data”` variable from the `useCallback` dependency array. I find it to be a good practice to not include a component state in the dependency arrays whenever possible.

If you need to change component state from the `useEffect` or `useCallback` and the new state is a function of the previous state, you can pass the function that receives a current state as parameter and returns a new state.

```
const updateData = useCallback(
    (period: PeriodFilter, asyncState: AsyncState<MyData[]>) => {
        const isSafeToSetData = isMounted === undefined || (isMounted !== undefined && isMounted());
        if (isSafeToSetData) {
            setData(existingData => new Map(existingData.set(period, asyncState)));
        }
    },
    [setData, isMounted]
);
```

In your example you need the current state only to calculate next state so that should work.

Comment: This should be upvoted more! I hadn't previously thought of solving it be using dependency injection (passing in the old data as an argument). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I now have based on @jure's comment above:

> I think the problem is that the "data" variable is included in the dependency array of useCallback. Every time you setData, the data variable is changed that triggers useCallback to provide new updateData and that triggers useEffect. Try to implement updateData without a dependecy on the data variable. you can do something like setData(d=>new Map(d.set(period, asyncState)) to avoid passing "data" variable to useCallback

I adjusted my code in the manners suggested and it worked. Thanks!

```
export function useDataByPeriod(dateRanges: PeriodFilter[]) {
    const isMounted = useMountedState();

    const [data, setData] = useState(
        new Map(
            dateRanges.map(dateRange => [
                dateRange,
                makeAsyncIsLoading({ isLoading: false }) as AsyncState<MyData[]>
            ])
        )
    );

    const updateData = useCallback(
        (period: PeriodFilter, asyncState: AsyncState<MyData[]>) => {
            const isSafeToSetData = isMounted === undefined || (isMounted !== undefined && isMounted());
            if (isSafeToSetData) {
                setData(existingData => new Map(existingData.set(period, asyncState)));
            }
        },
        [setData, isMounted]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (dateRanges.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        const loadData = () => {
            const client = makeClient();
            dateRanges.map(dateRange => {
                updateData(dateRange, makeAsyncIsLoading({ isLoading: true }));

                return client
                    .getData(dateRange.dateFrom, dateRange.dateTo)
                    .then(traffic => {
                        updateData(dateRange, makeAsyncData(traffic));
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        const errorString = `Problem fetching ${dateRange.displayPeriod} (${dateRange.dateFrom} - ${dateRange.dateTo})`;
                        console.error(errorString, error);
                        updateData(dateRange, makeAsyncError(errorString));
                    });
            });
        };

        loadData();
    }, [dateRanges , updateData]);

    return data;
}
```